# Assigning Default value in DateTime field in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Is it possible to assign DEFAULT rule for DateTime Field while adding a Work Item in TFS? But not using CLOCK value. Giving some Default Date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by hardcoding the value in the Work Item Type Definition.  In the appropriate TRANSITION element under the FIELDS\FIELD element for that field, instead of using ServerDefault and clock which you have probably seen like this:

```
<FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
  <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
</FIELD>
```

try doing this:

```
<FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
  <COPY from"value" value="01-Feb-2014" />
</FIELD>
```

Comment: I am not able to set the DEFAULT value. It shows error like "Value not supported by DateTime". Actually I have provided custom format like "dd-MM-yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, try this:

```
<FIELD name="Custom Date" refname="Custom.Date" type="DateTime">
  <DEFAULT from="value" value="2100-01-01" />
</FIELD>
```

The date that will be displayed is a day before of whatever date you're setting.